# How to append all subdivided polygon coordinates?

Tags: python, append, division

let `A` be set of coordinate (e.g. `array([[ 10., 110.],[200.,  90.],[210.,   0.], [-10.,  10.],[ 10., 110.]])`.
If `subdivision(coordinate)` is a division code, giving two outcomes - `subdivisionR, subdivisionL`, then `subdivision(A)` gives `array([[ 10., 110.],[110.0, 99.47],[110.0, 4.54],[-10., 10.],[ 10., 110.]]), array([[110.0, 99.47],[200.,90.],[210., 0.],[110.0, 4.54],[110.0, 99.47]])`.

Since I wanted to divide the polygon until all subdivided polygons reach the area closest to 200 and get all subdivided coordinates, I used following code;

```
n=1  
t=0  
r=0  
k=A  

while area(subdivision(k)[n-1])>200:
    for i in range(t,n):
        k.append(subdivision(k[i])[0])
        k.append(subdivision(k[i])[1])
    t=2**r
    r=r+1
    n=2**r
```

However, I get warning - `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'`.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for appending to a numpy array is different to say that of a python list.  You want to use:

```
numpy.append(array, value, axis)
```

So something like:

```
numpy.append(k, subdivision(k[i]), axis = 0)
```

Note axis is optional and would default to 1.  'value' is a numpy array, not a discrete value.

Comment: thank you! I'm not sure it works since tuple index of `area` and `subdivision` is different in while loops